# How to match a list item via RegExp in Robot Framework

Tags: regex, robotframework

I am trying to validate that a list of items all match a regular expression.

Here's an example of the list `${liabilityAccounts}` I'm working with:

```
[u'Liability: 100-0-20100 Payables', u'Liability: 100-0-20200 Credit Cards', u'Liability: 100-0-20300 Designated Funds', u'Liability: 100-0-20400 Miscellaneous Liabilities', u'Liability: 100-0-20500 DoH Liability', u'Liability: 200-0-20100 Payables']
```

I am trying to loop over these items to verify that each item matches the following format: "Liability: XXX-XX-2XXX" via:

```
:FOR  ${item}  IN  ${liabilityAccounts}
\  Should Match Regexp  ${item}  ^Liability: \\d{3}-\\d{1}-2\\d{4}.*$
```

I am receiving an error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your list `item` or `liabilityAccounts`?

Comment: liabilityAccounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When representing an array in a :FOR loop, you need to use `@` for the variable that contains the items to be iterated over. For example:

```
:FOR  ${item}  IN  @{liabilityAccounts}
```

Because you use a `$`, the loop will run exactly once, and  `${item}` will be set to the entire contents of the list. That is why you get a `TypeError`, because the keyword is being given a list rather than a string.

Here's a complete working example:

```
*** Variables ***
@{liabilityAccounts}  
...  Liability: 100-0-20100 Payables
...  Liability: 100-0-20200 Credit Cards
...  Liability: 100-0-20300 Designated Funds
...  Liability: 100-0-20400 Miscellaneous Liabilities
...  Liability: 100-0-20500 DoH Liability
...  Liability: 200-0-20100 Payables

*** Test cases ***
Example
    :FOR  ${item}  IN  ${liabilityAccounts}
    \  should match regexp  ${item}     ^Liability: \\d{3}-\\d{1}-2\\d{4}.*$
```